# Multiple Branch Merge

Tags: git, merge, branch, pull-request

I have the `master` branch.

I have created a branch `branch1` for a bugFix

Waiting the Pull Request merge i created `branch2` from `master` and merged `branch1` in it (in `branch2` i mean).

Then i worked on it.

Now, if i merge `branch1` into `master`, will the Pull Request of `branch2` be full of conflicts?

Or, thanks to the commit, will it 'understand' it?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your project's merge method.

If you Fast-forward merge, the commit's hash will change as you're altering the history through a rebase, therefore git won't be able to determine the already merged commit and the commit within your branch are the same.

If your project uses Merge commit, it should be fine.